# Why won't NVIDIA control panel change my settings?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

While tweaking around in the "Manage 3D Settings" and in the "Global Settings", I wanted to play around with some of the options, like change my performance mode to single display vs multiple display. When I apply the settings, an error message comes up saying, "Access Denied. Failed to apply selected settings to your system". Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: What version of the Nvidia drivers do you have?

Comment: @bfhd Newest drivers.

Comment: Which Windows/OS?

Comment: Which OS, which drivers (DirectX, nVidia), what video card, what monitor...

Can you please include information when you ask a question?

Comment: In my case the last folder in the directory path `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs` was missing. After creating the missing subfolder `Drs` I longer got the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Control Panel Client

Right Click On nvcplui.exe and Run As Admin

Thats work for me

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experienced this problem, but there are several possible solutions in this reddit thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/37j056/nvidia_control_panel_access_denied_failed_to/

---

Here are a few:

> 1. I had the exact issue after latest update (today) and I've fixed it by going to "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs" -> right click 
>      ->properties -> Previous Version (assuming you're system protection/system restore on c:) and restored the all the files with 
>      the most recent version... that's how I've solved the problem. In case
>      people want the pre-update files, I've uploaded'em:
>      http://www.2shared.com/file/vFlksc1J/Drs.html -> the go into the
>      following dir: "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\DRS"
>      https://forums.gefrce.com/default/topic/836061/geforce-experience/-solved-acces-denied-failed-to-apply-selected-settings-to-your-system-issue/post/4543709/#4543709
> 2. I fixed the error by removing all nVidia software and drivers,  reinstalling the 350.12 Driver and PhysX ONLY (no 3D drivers, no 
>      GFEX), then downloading the separate GeForce Experience package and 
>      installing that afterwards. Now I have access to my settings again, 
>      although all my presets and custom resolutions were reset.
>
>    3. I think I finally found the solution: uninstall all the nvidia drivers, > everything nvidia including the nvidia experience software
>         and restart. Then do a search for the drivers and manually download
>         them but do not download the experience software (choose custom
>         install to uncheck the option). I am now able to select my nvidia gpu
>         as default and it sticks (closed control panel and reopened to make
>         sure it was stuck on nvidia and not auto detect). Just tested it on
>         the game I was having a problem with and holy moly, night and day
>         difference. Hope this helps you all!

Good luck!

Comment: Doing a clean install fixed this issue. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where I have a notebook with NVIDIA Optimus, I wasn't able to change some configurations until I pressed the "VGA Button" which effectively "turns on" the Nvidia card.